# React JS, how can I disable an individual button in a mapped list?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, button, disable

New to react, I currently have a list of buttons mapped based off an api response like so:

```
render() { 
  return(
      <div> 
        <h4>User Status:</h4> 
        <div className='buttonContainer'>
        {this.state.data.map((status =>   
            <li key={status.key}>
              <button id={status.key} value = {status.text} onClick={this.nextStep}/>
                {status.text}
              </button>
            </li>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    )      
  }
```

The nextStep function changes a users status to whatever the value of the pressed button is (all based on the data) I don't want a user to be able to press a button multiple times however. How can I disable the button that was pressed without disabling every button in the list?

Answer (score 1):

Just add isDisabled flag in your state data array. Like below code

```
[{key: 1, text: 'aa', isDisabled: true}, {key: 1, text: 'ab', isDisabled: false}]
```

update this **isDisabled** flag on Button onClick event, Based on this isDisabled flag you can disable button click.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late response. I am not entirely sure I follow, will this disable the individual button that was pressed or the entire button array?